# Which Sentry SDK should I install for my application?

Tags: c++, ios, sentry

I currently have an iOS application written in C++/Qt and I want to integrate Sentry in my app. The problem is : I don't know which Sentry SDK I should use between `sentry-cocoa` and `sentry-native`.

How should I chose the SDK for my application ?

I tried installing `sentry-native` but I get this error :
`[sentry] DEBUG discarding envelope due to invalid transport`.
Does this mean that if I go with the native SDK, I will have to rewrite a transport ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some days experimenting, I came to the conclusion that I just needed to install the `sentry-cocoa` SDK for my application to be working !